# Line plot in pandas series generates extra indices

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Pandas series as follows:

```
2014    5668
2015    6024
2016    3903
Name: year, dtype: int64
```

I try to plot a line graph where x axis labels are years, and y axis labels are corresponding values. I do this:

```
ax = year_counts.plot(kind='line', figsize=[10, 5], marker='o')
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
ax.set_xticklabels(year_counts.index)rotation_mode='anchor', ha='center')
plt.show()
```

But when I check the graph, I see two extra x labels such as:

[image: Line plot]

I don't understand why this happens. If I remove the line with set_xticklabels, I don't have the same problem but then I have 0, 1, 2 as labels instead of 2014, 2015 and 2016.

It looks like I need at least five index-value pairs to generate a plot (as far as I understand). How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply specify the columns you like to plot in your `year_counts.plot()`? For example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[2014, 5668],
        [2015, 6024],
        [2016, 3903]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['years','value'])

df.plot('years', 'value')
```